# Problems with compiling apache2 on AIX 6.1

Tags: c, apache, shell, gcc, compiler-construction

While trying to compile the latest version of the apache web server(2.4.9) on my AIX 6.1 I run into a problem. When I run the `./configure --with-included-apr` command I got the following output:

```
checking for chosen layout... Apache
checking for working mkdir -p... yes
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking build system type... powerpc-ibm-aix6.1.0.0
checking host system type... powerpc-ibm-aix6.1.0.0
checking target system type... powerpc-ibm-aix6.1.0.0
configure:
configure: Configuring Apache Portable Runtime library...
configure:
configuring package in srclib/apr now
checking build system type... powerpc-ibm-aix6.1.0.0
checking host system type... powerpc-ibm-aix6.1.0.0
checking target system type... powerpc-ibm-aix6.1.0.0
Configuring APR library
Platform: powerpc-ibm-aix6.1.0.0
checking for working mkdir -p... yes
APR Version: 1.5.0
checking for chosen layout... apr
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/stud/config/usr/admin/gaara/httpd-2.4.9/srclib/apr':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
configure failed for srclib/apr
```

and the config.log is also attached below.

```
    This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by configure, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ /stud/config/usr/admin/gaara/httpd-2.4.9/srclib/apr/configure --disable-option-checking --with-included-apr --cache-file=/dev/null --srcdir=/stud/config/usr/admin/gaara/httpd-2.4.9/srclib/apr --prefix=/usr/local/apache2 --exec-prefix=/usr/local/apache2 --libdir=${prefix}/lib --includedir=/usr/local/apache2/include --bindir=${prefix}/bin --datadir=/usr/local/apache2 --with-installbuilddir=${prefix}/build

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = stud.project.com
uname -m = 00C0E76C4C00
uname -r = 1
uname -s = AIX
uname -v = 6

/usr/bin/uname -p = powerpc
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = 6.1.0.0
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: .
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/ucb
PATH: /usr/ccs/bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /sybase
PATH: /sybase/OCS-15_0/bin
PATH: /usr/java5_64/bin
PATH: /usr/java5_64/jre/bin
PATH: /opt/apache-tomcat-5.5.25/bin
PATH: /opt/apache-maven-3.1.1/bin
PATH: /usr/vacpp/bin
PATH: /usr/ucb
PATH: /usr/ccs/bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /sybase
PATH: /sybase/OCS-15_0/bin
PATH: /dun/pvcspkg/pvcs81_aix/vm/aix/bin
PATH: /opt/apache-ant-1.8.4/bin
PATH: /stud/app_code/classes
PATH: /mftps


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:4596: checking build system type
configure:4610: result: powerpc-ibm-aix6.1.0.0
configure:4630: checking host system type
configure:4643: result: powerpc-ibm-aix6.1.0.0
configure:4663: checking target system type
configure:4676: result: powerpc-ibm-aix6.1.0.0
configure:4739: checking for working mkdir -p
configure:4755: result: yes
configure:4847: checking for chosen layout
configure:4849: result: apr
configure:5114: checking for gcc
configure:5130: found /usr/bin/gcc
configure:5141: result: gcc
configure:5370: checking for C compiler version
configure:5379: gcc --version >&5
gcc (GCC) 4.0.0
Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:5390: $? = 0
configure:5379: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
Target: powerpc-ibm-aix5.3.0.0
Configured with: ../configure --with-as=/usr/bin/as --with-ld=/usr/bin/ld --disable-nls --enable-languages=c,c++ --prefix=/opt/freeware --enable-threads --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --host=powerpc-ibm-aix5.3.0.0
Thread model: aix
gcc version 4.0.0
configure:5390: $? = 0
configure:5379: gcc -V >&5
gcc: '-V' option must have argument
configure:5390: $? = 1
configure:5379: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc: unrecognized option '-qversion'
gcc: no input files
configure:5390: $? = 1
configure:5410: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:5432: gcc    conftest.c  >&5
Assembler:
/tmp//ccrBCCo6.s: line 10: Only .llong should be used for relocatable expressions.
configure:5436: $? = 1
configure:5474: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:5479: error: in `/stud/config/usr/admin/gaara/httpd-2.4.9/srclib/apr':
configure:5481: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=powerpc-ibm-aix6.1.0.0
ac_cv_env_CC_set=''
ac_cv_env_CC_value=''
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=''
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=''
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=''
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=''
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=''
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=''
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=''
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=''
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=''
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=''
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=''
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=''
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=''
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=''
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=''
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=''
ac_cv_host=powerpc-ibm-aix6.1.0.0
ac_cv_mkdir_p=yes
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc
ac_cv_target=powerpc-ibm-aix6.1.0.0

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ALLOCA=''
APR_CONFIG_LOCATION='source'
APR_DOTTED_VERSION='1.5.0'
APR_LIBNAME=''
APR_MAJOR_VERSION='1'
AR=''
AS=''
ASCPP=''
AWK=''
CC='gcc'
CFLAGS=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
DEFAULT_OSDIR=''
DEFS=''
DLLTOOL=''
DSYMUTIL=''
DUMPBIN=''
ECHO_C='\c'
ECHO_N=''
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
EXEEXT=''
EXTRA_CFLAGS=''
EXTRA_CPPFLAGS=''
EXTRA_INCLUDES=''
EXTRA_LDFLAGS=''
EXTRA_LIBS=''
FGREP=''
GREP=''
INCLUDES=''
INCLUDE_OUTPUTS=''
INCLUDE_RULES=''
INSTALL_DATA=''
INSTALL_PROGRAM=''
INSTALL_SCRIPT=''
INSTALL_SUBDIRS=''
INTERNAL_CPPFLAGS=''
LD=''
LDFLAGS=''
LDLIBS=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LIBTOOL=''
LIBTOOL_LIBS=''
LIPO=''
LN_S=''
LTFLAGS=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
LT_LDFLAGS=''
LT_NO_INSTALL=''
LT_VERSION=''
MANIFEST_TOOL=''
MKDEP=''
NM=''
NMEDIT=''
NOTEST_CFLAGS=''
NOTEST_CPPFLAGS=''
NOTEST_INCLUDES=''
NOTEST_LDFLAGS=''
NOTEST_LIBS=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJECTS_PLATFORM=''
OBJEXT=''
OSDIR=''
OTOOL64=''
OTOOL=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME=''
PACKAGE_STRING=''
PACKAGE_TARNAME=''
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION=''
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
RANLIB=''
RM=''
SED=''
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/sh'
STRIP=''
ac_ct_AR=''
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
ac_ct_DUMPBIN=''
acceptfilter=''
apr_builddir='/stud/config/usr/admin/gaara/httpd-2.4.9/srclib/apr'
apr_builders='/stud/config/usr/admin/gaara/httpd-2.4.9/srclib/apr/build'
apr_charset_ebcdic=''
apr_has_user=''
apr_has_xthread_files=''
apr_inaddr_none=''
apr_procattr_user_set_requires_password=''
apr_srcdir='/stud/config/usr/admin/gaara/httpd-2.4.9/srclib/apr'
apr_tcp_nopush_flag=''
apr_thread_func=''
aprdso=''
aprlfs=''
arpa_ineth=''
bigendian=''
bindir='${prefix}/bin'
build='powerpc-ibm-aix6.1.0.0'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='powerpc'
build_os='aix6.1.0.0'
build_vendor='ibm'
conioh=''
crypth=''
ctypeh=''
datadir='/usr/local/apache2'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
direnth=''
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
eolstr=''
errnoh=''
exec_prefix='/usr/local/apache2'
export_lib_target=''
fcntlh=''
fcntlser=''
file_as_socket=''
flockser=''
fork=''
hasfcntlser=''
hasflockser=''
hasposixser=''
hasprocpthreadser=''
hassysvser=''
have_corkable_tcp=''
have_getrlimit=''
have_in_addr=''
have_inet_addr=''
have_inet_network=''
have_iovec=''
have_ipv6=''
have_memchr=''
have_memmove=''
have_proc_invoked=''
have_sa_storage=''
have_sctp=''
have_setrlimit=''
have_sigaction=''
have_sigsuspend=''
have_sigwait=''
have_strcasecmp=''
have_strdup=''
have_stricmp=''
have_strncasecmp=''
have_strnicmp=''
have_strstr=''
have_unicode_fs=''
have_union_semun=''
havebeosarea=''
havemmapanon=''
havemmapshm=''
havemmaptmp=''
havemmapzero=''
haveos2shm=''
haveshmget=''
haveshmgetanon=''
havewin32shm=''
host='powerpc-ibm-aix6.1.0.0'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='powerpc'
host_os='aix6.1.0.0'
host_vendor='ibm'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='/usr/local/apache2/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
ino_t_value=''
installbuilddir='${datadir}/build-${APR_MAJOR_VERSION}'
int64_literal=''
int64_t_fmt=''
int64_value=''
int_value=''
ioh=''
lib_target=''
libdir='${prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/modules'
limitsh=''
link=''
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}'
long_value=''
lt_compile=''
mandir='${prefix}/man'
mmap=''
netdbh=''
netinet_inh=''
netinet_sctp_uioh=''
netinet_sctph=''
netinet_tcph=''
o_nonblock_inherited=''
oc=''
off_t_fmt=''
off_t_value=''
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
osuuid=''
pdfdir='${docdir}'
pid_t_fmt=''
posixser=''
prefix='/usr/local/apache2'
proc_mutex_is_global=''
processh=''
proclockglobal=''
procpthreadser=''
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
pthreadh=''
pthreadser=''
rand=''
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
semaphoreh=''
sendfile=''
sharedmem=''
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
shlibpath_var=''
short_value=''
signalh=''
size_t_fmt=''
size_t_value=''
so_ext=''
socklen_t_value=''
ssize_t_fmt=''
ssize_t_value=''
stdargh=''
stdint=''
stdioh=''
stdlibh=''
stringh=''
stringsh=''
struct_rlimit=''
sys_ioctlh=''
sys_sendfileh=''
sys_signalh=''
sys_socketh=''
sys_sockioh=''
sys_syslimitsh=''
sys_timeh=''
sys_typesh=''
sys_uioh=''
sys_unh=''
sys_waith=''
sysconfdir='${prefix}/conf'
sysvser=''
target='powerpc-ibm-aix6.1.0.0'
target_alias=''
target_cpu='powerpc'
target_os='aix6.1.0.0'
target_vendor='ibm'
tcp_nodelay_inherited=''
threads=''
timeh=''
top_builddir='/stud/config/usr/admin/gaara/httpd-2.4.9/srclib/apr'
uint64_literal=''
uint64_t_fmt=''
uint64_t_hex_fmt=''
unistdh=''
usebeosarea=''
usemmapanon=''
usemmapshm=''
usemmaptmp=''
usemmapzero=''
useos2shm=''
useshmget=''
useshmgetanon=''
usewin32shm=''
voidp_size=''
windowsh=''
winsock2h=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME ""
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
#define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
#define PACKAGE_STRING ""
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_URL ""

configure: exit 77
```

How do I solve this issue.

Comment: You should include the `config.log` in `srclib/apr`, not the one in top directory.

Comment: It seems that the configure script thinks that gcc isn't working. The error message says `checking whether the C compiler works... no`. If there's no working C compiler, then it cannot make any executables from source.

Comment: Are you compiling with root user?

Comment: @ Rahul R Dhobi : No, as a normal user.

Comment: @DarkMatter It looks like your GNU toolchain does not work properly.

Comment: I notice that I can compile c programs using either `setenv OBJECT_MODE 32` or  `gcc -maix64 test.c`, can I leverage either of these to solve this issue.

Comment: If you can only compile using either of those 2, it means that the default target architecture isn't aix64. Can you try setting environment variable `GCC="gcc -maix64"`. So you will run your configure as `GCC="gcc -maix64" ./configure --with-included-apr`.